# showing all related contacts in an account custom field

Tags: trigger

hey i am trying to write down a trigger in which all related contact lastname of an account will show in an account custom field. i wrote down this trigger and the problem is it is showing only latest contact please help me with this.

## here is the trigger

```
trigger Textareaupdate on Contact (after insert) {
    List<account> lstacc=new List<account>();

    for(contact con:trigger.new){
        account acc=new account();

        acc.Contact_Name_area__c=con.LastName;

        acc.Id=con.AccountId;
        lstacc.add(acc);
    }
    update lstacc;
}
```

Comment: Try appending '__r' for getting the related contacts with account. for example :

`for(contact con:trigger.new){
        account acc=new account();
       acc.Contact_Name_area__c=con.contact__r.Name;         
    }`

Comment: try the soql query somthing like `SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<valid_id>'` and loop through the record for getting the contact.

Comment: showing contact__r does not exist

Comment: see this link will cater your requirement. hope this will help
[Get related list inside trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AcdaIAC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to query for all the `Contacts` that are related to the `Account`, your code only updates the latest `Contact` that is being created under the `Account`. Hence, `Contact_Name_area__c` field will always contain the latest `Contact` name.

Also, you cannot loop through `Contact` records i.e. `Trigger.New` context variable and achieve this, when you are looping through `Trigger.New`, it will only contain the records which are in context i.e. which are in transaction. Whereas, you need all the `Contacts` under that `Account`, which will need a `SOQL` query either on `Account` or on `Contact`.

Your trigger should be something like this

```
trigger Textareaupdate on Contact (after insert) {    
    Set<id> AccIdList = new Set<id>();
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    List<String> conNames = new List<String>();
    for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
        AccIdList.add(con.accountid);
    }
    for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Name_area__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : AccIdList]){
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
            conNames.add(con.LastName);
        }
        acc.Contact_Name_area__c = String.join(conNames, ', ');
        accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
        conNames.clear();
    }    
    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

**Note :** This trigger will work only on insert context i.e. if you update any `Contact's` `LastName`, then it won't be reflected in `Account's` `Contact_Name_area__c` field.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked